# Help fixing Apex Error

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, error, code

Does anyone know how I fix this error in my aura lightning component? My action isn't retrieving the Opportunity records anymore. It was working fine last month, but has stopped working. I am new to coding and any assistance would be great! Thank you

[image]

APEX:

```
   public with sharing class UpdateExistingPaxController {

   @AuraEnabled
public static List <Opportunity> fetchOpportunity(String oppRecordId) {

    return [SELECT Id, Name, Trip_File_LEAD__c
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE Lead_PAX__c = :oppRecordId];  
   
}
```

COMPONENT:

```
   <aura:component controller="UpdateExistingPaxController"
            implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="OpportunityList" type="List" access="global" />
<!-- <aura:attribute name="SyncedQuoteId" type="Id" /> -->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.loadOpportunities}"/>
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.loadOpportunities}" />

<div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-end"> 
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.updateFields}">Update</button>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
  ({


loadOpportunities: function(component, event, helper) {
    var recordId = component.get('v.recordId')

    var action = component.get('c.fetchOpportunity');
     action.setParams({oppRecordId:recordId});
          action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {

            component.set('v.OpportunityList', response.getReturnValue());
            component.find("box3").set("v.value", false);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

response.getError()

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably caused by this update - https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2020/critical-update-ensure-users-have-access-to-auraenabled-methods

which removed automatic access to @AuraEnabled methods for signed in users.

In order to give a user access to @AuraEnabled method, go to the profile, click 'enabled apex class access' and then add the class in question to the 'enabled' list. Alternatively, create a permission set to do the same.